# Deploying Quasar with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting, quasar-framework, quasar

[image]

I'm having trouble deploying my quasar project to Firebase. It says the deployment was successful, but after two hours, this is what shows up on the webpage.

firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
   "public": "dist/spa",
   "ignore": [
     "firebase.json",
     "**/.*",
     "**/node_modules/**"
   ],
   "rewrites": [
     {
       "source": "**",
       "destination": "/index.html"
     }
   ]
```

routes.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '', component: () => import('pages/PageUsers.vue') },
      { path: '/chat/:otherUserId', component: () => import('pages/PageChat.vue') },
      { path: '/auth', component: () => import('pages/AuthPage.vue') }

    ]
  },

  // Always leave this as last one,
  // but you can also remove it
  {
    path: '*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  }
]

export default routes
```

I first ran quasar build, then firebase init, then firebase deploy yet nothing is showing up on the site yet. Any ideas to why this is happening?

Update: Now the same page is showing on http://localhost:8080/ instead of my project as well

Answer (score 2):

If you build first, "firebase init" will overwrite your index.html.

1. Firebase init
2. Run quasar build
3. Firebase deploy

Did you try in this order?

I also had the same problem but, after I changed the order, then it worked as usual.

Answer (score 2):

It is because Firebase is overwriting your index.html with its own index.html, to fix that:

1. run `quasar build -m spa` to generate the correct index.html
2. run `firebase init` and when it asks you to overwrite index.html select 'No' like this:
   [image: Step by step firebase]
3. run `firebase deploy`

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue while setting up Quasar project with Firebase hosting.
One thing I noticed was there was a new `index.html` generated during firebase init inside the `public` folder.
After deleting `public/index.html`, the original index page displays properly.

**Solution:**

- Check if there is an `index.html` file generated in `public` folder
- Delete the file